# How to translate fields in django models

Tags: python, django, locale, translate

I try to translate fields in model like this:

my model:

```
class CompletedWork(models.Model):
period = models.ForeignKey(directory.Period,
                           on_delete=models.SET('deleted date'),
                           verbose_name=_("Period"),
                           )
worker = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.SET('deleted worker'),
    related_name='worker_do',
    verbose_name=_('Worker'),
    default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
)
work_done = models.ForeignKey(directory.WorksType,
                              on_delete=models.SET('deleted works type'),
                              verbose_name=_('Work done')
                              )
work_scope = models.FloatField(_("Work scope"), blank=True, null=True)
work_notes = models.CharField(_("Comments"), max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, )
record_author = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.SET('deleted user'),
    related_name='record_author', auto_created=True,
)
record_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
checked_by_head = models.BooleanField(default=False)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I don't understand why worker and work_done fields doesn't translated. in my locale:

```
msgid "Add record"
msgstr "Додати запис"

msgid "Period"
msgstr "Період"

msgid "Worker"
msgstr "Працівник"

msgid "Work done"
msgstr "Виконана робота"

msgid "Work scope"
msgstr "Обсяг роботи"
```

So I see that:

```
period - translated
worker - not translated
work_done - not translated
work_scope - translated
work_notes - translated
```

[image]

in documentation says that you can mark names of ForeignKey, ManyToManyField or OneToOneField relationship as translatable by using their verbose_name options:

```
class MyThing(models.Model):
kind = models.ForeignKey(
    ThingKind,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='kinds',
    verbose_name=_('kind'),
)
```

Why it doesn't work right in my situation?

Comment: Are you sure to using the `gettext_lazy` from `django.utils.translation`, instead of `gettext` ?

Comment: yes, i imported it like this: - from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _